# OpenCV image size limit

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to pass a huge Mat image (98304x51968) between openCV and itk using the ITK to openCV Bridge. I have an error :

> Insufficient memory (OverFlow for imageSize) in cvIniyImageHeader,
> file opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp line 2961.

Does this mean that opencv has a limit on the size of images?

Comment: The error message indicates more running out of memory than some OpenCV limit. What is your amout of RAM? Note that your image has almost 5 gigapixels. How many bits per pixel it uses?

Comment: 8 pixels and i have 156 GB, so it's not a RAM problem. I find a topic that talk about similar problem : https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7507

Comment: If on Linux or macOS, try running `ulimit -a` to see if you have restrictions on memory you may allocate.

Comment: It's windows, so i dont think so.

Comment: OpenCV has image size limits, but your error is still an "insufficuent memory". Can you try to malloc the same amount of memory manually instead? Should be close to 39 GB if you really have 8 channels per pixel.  Maybe your RAM is split between CPUs or fragmented or sth.

Comment: What is your OpenCV version? There is a related PR: [handle huge matrices correctly #11505](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11505)

Comment: I'm sorry Micka. i's one channel with 8U type.

Comment: I'm using 4.0.0 pre Catree

Comment: ok, still 4,7 GB. Did you try to malloc the same amount of data manually? Can you have a look at opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp the imageSize variable? Does it allow values of +5108662272? Maybe there is an overflow in the variable value? For example, unsigned int (32 bit) can only hold max value +4294967295 which could explain the error if variable overflows are somehow detected (and not just allocated 1100000000 bytes after overflow occured), but hopefully the imageSize variable is just a size_t...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, since this pull request: [handle huge matrices correctly #11505](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11505), you should be able to do something like this (code taken from the test):

```
Mat m(65000, 40000, CV_8U);
ASSERT_FALSE(m.isContinuous());

uint64 i, n = (uint64)m.rows*m.cols;
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    m.data[i] = (uchar)(i & 255);

cv::threshold(m, m, 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
int nz = cv::countNonZero(m);  // FIXIT 'int' is not enough here (overflow is possible with other inputs)
ASSERT_EQ((uint64)nz, n / 2);
```

Since `countNonZero()` returns an `int`, overflow is possible. This means that you should be able to create huge matrix but not all OpenCV function can handle correctly huge matrix.

---

Regarding your issue, this is the code for [`ITKImageToCVMat`](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/v5.0a02/Modules/Video/BridgeOpenCV/include/itkOpenCVImageBridge.hxx#L253-L262) in `v5.0a02`:

```
template<typename TInputImageType>
cv::Mat
OpenCVImageBridge::ITKImageToCVMat(const TInputImageType* in, bool force3Channels)
{
  // Extra copy, but necessary to prevent memory leaks
  IplImage* temp = ITKImageToIplImage<TInputImageType>(in, force3Channels);
  cv::Mat out = cv::cvarrToMat( temp, true );
  cvReleaseImage(&temp);
  return out;
}
```

As you can see, `IplImage` image is still used and should be the source of your error.
Your best option currently should be to do the conversion yourself. Maybe something like (I don't know ITK, same input and output type, one channel):

```
typename ImageType::RegionType  region = in->GetLargestPossibleRegion();
typename ImageType::SizeType    size = region.GetSize();
unsigned int w = static_cast< unsigned int >( size[0] );
unsigned int h = static_cast< unsigned int >( size[1] );
Mat m(h, w, CV_8UC1, in->GetBufferPointer());
```

No copy is involved here. If you want to copy, you can do:

```
Mat m_copy = m.clone();
```

Comment: Thank you Catree. Indeed, i did it myself and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a signed int (typically 32 bit) limitation in IplImage:
From the named .cpp file here's the code snippet that leads to the error:

```
const int64 imageSize_tmp = (int64)image->widthStep*(int64)image->height;
image->imageSize = (int)imageSize_tmp;
if( (int64)image->imageSize != imageSize_tmp )
    CV_Error( CV_StsNoMem, "Overflow for imageSize" );
```

Which looks like (without checking) `image->imageSize` is a 32 bit signed int and this part of the code will detect and handle overflows. According to your posted link in the comments, the IplImage "bug" might got fixed (I didn't check that), so MAYBE you can remove this overflow detection step in the OpenCV code for newer IplImage versions, but that's just a guess and has to be confirmed. You'll have to check the type of `image->imageSize`. If it is a 64 bit type, you can probably change the openCV code to support Mats bigger than 2147483647 bytes.

EDIT: REMARK: I checked the code in OpenCV 3.4 but the code line was the right one, so probably in Version 4.0 there's no change yet.

If your are sure that the IplImage limitation got fixed, you can try this:

```
const int64 imageSize_tmp = (int64)image->widthStep*(int64)image->height;
image->imageSize = imageSize_tmp; // imageSize isn't 32 bit signed int anymore!
//if( (int64)image->imageSize != imageSize_tmp ) // no overflow detection necessary anymore
//    CV_Error( CV_StsNoMem, "Overflow for imageSize" ); // no overflow detection necessary anymore
```

but better make sure that IplImage's imageSize is 64 bit now ;)

UPDATE: The linked fix in https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7507/commits/a89aa8c90a625c78e40f4288d145996d9cda3599 ADDED the overflow detection, so PROBABLY IplImage still has the 32 bit int imageSize limitation! Be careful here!

Comment: `int` is so much faster typed than `size_t` :D

Comment: You can do this now ([see](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/11505)) with `Mat`: `Mat m;` `m.create(65000, 40000, CV_8U);`. `IplImage` should not be used at all in modern OpenCV (>= 2.4).

Comment: probably IplImages are created internally when OpenCV is used with IPP support?