# Remove OpenCV image size limitation

Tags: python, opencv

I am loading in a very large image (60,000 x 80,000 pixels) and am exceeding the max pixels I can load:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:75: 
    error: (-215:Assertion failed) pixels <= CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS in function 'validateInputImageSize'
```

From what I have found this is referring to the limitation imposed on [line 65](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8eba3c1e7e8975ff1d263a41a5753efaa51d54fc/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L65)

Ideally I'd change that to deal with at least 5 gigapixel images

```
#define CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS (1<<33)
```

I have seen some workarounds for this ([OpenCV image size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493373/opencv-image-size-limit)) but those don't seem to address the problem which is an arbitrary definition (I'm working off a high performance server with 700gb ram so compute not an issue).

My issue is that **I have no idea where this file is**. The error points me towards this "travis" directory which doesn't exist locally for me and in my local environment the c++ files aren't available.

Any idea on where to look to find the c++ library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to modify the openCV source files and then compile it your own.

EDIT: You can also modify environment variables

```
export CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS=1099511627776
```

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. Do you know why this is a limitation in the first place?

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10211

Answer (score 3):

For my problem I should have specified it was a .tif file (NOTE most large images will be in this file format anyway). In which case a very easy way to load it in to a numpy array (so it can then work with OpenCV) is with the package tifffile.

```
pip install tifffile as tifi
```

This will install it in your python environment.

```
import tifffile as tifi
img = tifi.imread("VeryLargeFile.tif")
```

From here you can use it as you would with any numpy array and it is fully compatible with OpenCV etc.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to your program should fix the issue in python opencv.

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS"] = str(pow(2,40))
import cv2
```